# cv2 can't find an attribiute optflow even though it is imported

Tags: python, opencv

I am using cv2 and everything was ok, I was using all of those functions etc, but I don't know why cv2 can't recognize optlow. When I try to use it I got:

```
flowSTD = cv2.optflow.calcOpticalFlowSparseToDense(gray, gray2, grid_step=5, sigma=0.5)
```

> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'optflow'

as I mentioned above, I can use funcionts like Lucas Kanade. Below Pictures:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45u9u.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywh4W.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask]. Include your code as a [mcve] instead.

Comment: You are using the newer version of OpenCV. The older versions follow `cv2.optflow.calcOpticalFlowSparseToDense`. Check out the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install opencv-contrib-python

```
$ pip install opencv-contrib-python

>>> import cv2
>>> flowSTD = cv2.optflow.calcOpticalFlowSparseToDense(gray, gray2, grid_step=5, sigma=0.5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'gray' is not defined
```

Comment: please do NOT recommend to install BOTH, as the latter already includes the former